# Does the use of kernels in SVMs increase the chances of overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning

When using kernels to delimit non linear domains in SVMs, we introduce new features based on the training examples. We then have as many features as training examples. But having as many features as examples increases the chances of overfitting right? Should we drop some of these new features?

Comment: This question should not be on hold for failing to demonstrate a minimal understanding. The question is actually quite valid. Part of the curse of dimensionality is overfitting in high dimensional spaces - which can be counter intuitive when we use the RBF kernel which is technically solving the problem in an infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really can't drop any of the kernel-generated features, in many cases you don't know what features are being used or what weight is being given to them. In addition to the usage of kernels, SVMs use regularization, and this regularization decreases the possibility of overfitting.

You can read about the connection between the formulation of SVMs and statistical learning theory, but the high level summary is that the SVM doesn't just find a separating hyperplane but finds one that maximizes the margin.

The wikipedia article for [SVMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) is very good and provides excellent links to regularization, and parameter search and many other important topics.

Comment: Regularization does not really explain why SVMs still obtain good accuracy in high (or infinite) projected spaces, as the kernel perception can obtain similar (though lesser) accuracies on the same data. The kernel perceptron has no regularization and no convergence guarantees.

Comment: @Raff.Edward No regularization is openly debatable. (Kernel) perceptrons are usually trained using early stopping, which in a sense is equivalent to regularization. You should perhaps take a look at this: http://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2004_links_icml.pdf

Comment: Regularization is not debatable. It usually helps in absence of obscene amounts of data. Also, Kernel perceptions are not trained using early stopping. They are simple stopped after an arbitrary number of iterations because the perceptron does not converge on non-linearly separable data. The fact is most papers simple perform one epoch through the data set as most consider the Perceptron from an online perspective (see papers for: Projection, RBP, Stoptron, Forgetron, DUOL). The paper you linked is not about the standard Perceptron, and is about approximating the SVM through the Margin Percept

Comment: The fact is, regularization does not fully explain why we can learn well in high projected spaces.

Comment: @Raff.Edward: Perceptrons have no explicit regularization term. But saying perceptrons have no regularization is debatable. There is a close connection between early stopping/finding a good number of epochs on held out data/using epoch=1 and regularization. If you don't do this you you will overfit.

Answer (score 0):

increasing feature did increase the chances of overfitting,may be you should use cross validation（libsvm contains） strategy to test the model you trained now is overfitting or not,
and use feature seletion tools to select feature http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/fselect/fselect.py